# Why isn't argument of brk(void *end_data_segment), rounded up to the next page boundary?

Tags: c, linux, brk

From *The Linux Programming Interface*:

```
int brk(void * end_data_segment );
```

> The `brk()` system call sets the program break to the location specified
>   by `end_data_segment`. Since virtual memory is allocated in units of
>   pages, `end_data_segment` is effectively rounded up to the next page
>   boundary.

So for this demo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long int page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    printf("My page size: %ld\n", page_size);
    void* c1 = sbrk(0);
    printf("program break address: %p\n", c1);
    printf("sizeof char: %lu\n", sizeof(char));
    c1 = (void*) ((char*) c1 + 1);
    printf("c1: %p\n", c1);
    brk(c1);
    void* c2 = sbrk(0);
    printf("program break address: %p\n", c2); 

}
```

output:

```
My page size: 4096
program break address: 0x55b0bc104000
sizeof char: 1
c1: 0x55b0bc104001
program break address: 0x55b0bc104001
```

I expect the new program break address to be: `0x55b0bc104000 + 0x1000(4096 in HEX) == 0x55b0bc105000`

Why didn't I get `0x55b0bc105000` but `0x55b0bc104001` instead?

Comment: Two (unrelated) things: First of all the size of `char` is specified to *always* be `1`. You really don't have to print it. Secondly, the correct format to print a `size_t` value (as given by e.g. `sizeof`) is `%zu`. Mismatching format specifier and type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as 2 possibilities:

- align the `end_data_segment` to a page boundary; and ensure that the size of the underlying area of the virtual address space exactly matches the `end_data_segment` value
- don't align the `end_data_segment` to a page boundary; and ensure that the size of the underlying area of the virtual address space is aligned (rounded up) to the page size

For the first possibility, portable software (that has no idea what the page size will be) could (e.g.) increase the `end_data_segment` by 1/8th of a page and do that 8 separate times, and instead of ending up with one extra page (the result you'd naturally expect) it would end up with 8 extra pages (7 pages more than it wanted and 7 pages more than it expected). Worse; software could reduce the size of `end_data_segment` by less than a page and it would do nothing (would be rounded back up to what the original value); and this can also be done many times leading to a large area that software tried to get rid of but still exists. Of course these can be combined - software could increase `end_data_segment` by 1 byte and then reduce `end_data_segment` by one byte in the middle of a loop, causing an unexpected memory (space) leak that might quickly gobble up all available virtual address space when people expected it to waste nothing. Of course software could explicitly work around all the problems by adding (non-standard/unportable) fix-ups everywhere, but that would be horribly ugly.

The second possibility (don't align the `end_data_segment`) is more intuitive, more convenient, and less error prone.

Comment: So the book is wrong and `brk`  is using the second method?

Comment: @Rick: There's a subtle difference between the words "end_data_segment is effectively rounded up to the next page boundary" and "end_data_segment is rounded up to the next page boundary" - the "effectively" implies that it's not rounded up but behaves as if it was (which is close to the second possibility and not wrong).