# I want to test my function to get a segmentation fault, this don't happen

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, malloc

I want to make a basic implementation of the malloc function.

Rigth now, I can do a simple memory allocation by using my function.

My problem is that when I want to test my function to get a segmentation fault, this don't happen.

Could you give me some help ?

Thank You by advance

```
#include <stdio.h>

void *malloc(size_t size)
{
    mem_space *space;

    space = sbrk(0);
    space->value = sbrk(sizeof(mem_space) + size);
    return (space->value);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = NULL;
    char *str2 = NULL;

    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
    str[0] = 'T';
    str[1] = 'E';
    str[2] = 'S';
    str[3] = 'T';
    str[4] = '\n';
    printf("%s", str);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: "I want to test my function to get a segmentation fault, this don't happen." --> post the code used to attempt to achieve the seg fault.  Best: [mcve]

Comment: `brk`, `sbrk` and `mmap` all round up the size argument to the nearest page boundary, and a page is generally 4KiB. So even if you want to allocate 4 bytes with your function, it'll probably allocate 4096 bytes.

Comment: Not an answer, but note that Sbrk is deprecated for allocation purposes, and you might want to mmap instead

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Are you sure about `brk` and `sbrk`? I knew about `mmap` but I can't find this info about `brk`

Comment: @Adalcar I personally found out about `brk` rounding up first. When trying to make my own `malloc`, I stumbled upon this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729938/why-isnt-argument-of-brkvoid-end-data-segment-rounded-up-to-the-next-page-b where OP quotes an exerpt from _The Linux Programming Interface_: "The `brk()` system call sets the program break to the location specified by `end_data_segment`. Since virtual memory is allocated in units of pages, `end_data_segment` is effectively rounded up to the next page boundary." `sbrk` is a wrapper around `brk`, so it'll round up too.

Comment: Note that the Wikipedia page of the page states that: "... It is the smallest unit of data for memory management in a virtual memory operating system."

Comment: Yup, makes sense now, my life is a lie and kernel linux programmers are too smart for me

Comment: @Adalcar Haha, that's fine, I still have much to learn about Linux system calls myself. I suggest you note the page size issue in your answer though, some people tend to skip over the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In your `main`, you use `malloc(sizeof(char*) * 4)`.

`sizeof(char*)` is the size of a pointer, which is 4 in 32-bits and 8 in 64-bits.

In both cases, you are actually allocating 16 or 32 bytes of memory, that is, a lot more than you are using. Thus, you will not get any error that way.

You should use `sizeof(char)` instead.

#### EDIT:

As mentioned by @mediocrevegetable1 in the comments:

Sbrk and Brk move the program data segment in the kernel segment table, which has a page-by-page (4096-bytes) granularity.

This means that even though you allocate only 4 or 16 bytes, you will not encounter an actual segmentation fault unless you reach the end of the page (your address is a multiple of 0x1000)

Comment: Hmm... the standard mandates that `sizeof(char)` is `1`. Said differently I have never written it in my many years of C programmer...

Comment: @SergeBallesta True, I use it mostly for consistency with the rest, so that I always use a `sizeof` in my malloc calls

Comment: No problem. As long as you are aware of it, it is close to a matter of taste...

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault is not generated by the `malloc` library but by the OS.

So you cannot develop a test for your library to generate a seg fault.

Comment: A Segmentation fault is generated by the OS when trying to access unallocated data (more precisely outside of your data segment). So he was correct in his idea that trying to access data he didn't allocate himself could generate a segfault.